# Qt stops refreshing

Tags: image, qt, video, process, stream

We used Qt to develop a software similar to video surveillance, but what we connected was not a surveillance camera, but an industrial camera, using a Gigabit Ethernet interface, and the maximum frame rate of the video stream transmitted by each camera is 30 frames. We use sub-threads to receive camera data. After each frame of data is received, the GUI main thread is notified by a signal-slot method to call the Widget's update function to draw frame images.

The problem I am currently encountering is:

When only one camera is connected, the software can display the video stream image of the camera normally for a long time; but when we connect four cameras at the same time, after a few minutes of normal display, the pictures of the four cameras will not be refreshed. After I clicked the window with the mouse (manually forced to refresh), the 4 cameras can be refreshed normally again.

What is this question? How to solve it? grateful!

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your application's memory usage over time?  Since you're using multiple threads (and, hence, queued connections) there may be a gradual build up of pending events in the main/GUI thread's event queue.  If each event contains a video frame then that could easily result in things getting 'bogged down'.  Without seeing the code, though, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I have monitored memory and found no memory leaks. Is the update function called too often? One camera calls the update function about 30 times per second, and four cameras about 120 times per second.

Comment: Just to clarify in case there was any misunderstanding, my previous comment was with regard to increasing memory usage *not* memory leaks -- they're not the same thing.